# How to terminate gen_server gracefully without crash report

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, lager

In my gen_server I am terminating it like this:

```
handle_info({'EXIT', _From, _Reason}, State) ->
    {stop, partner_fled, State};
```

But still logger prints it out as an error

```
14:56:43.349 [error] gen_server <0.3290.0> terminated with reason: partner_fled
14:56:43.349 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.3290.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: partner_fled in gen_server:terminate/7 line 812
```

The code is working as intended, but I don't want the logger to print it out as its a graceful termination.

By the way I am using lager, but I think removing it will only change the format of logging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the manual](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:terminate-2):

> Notice that for any other reason than `normal`, `shutdown`, or `{shutdown,Term}`, the `gen_server` process is assumed to terminate because of an error and an error report is issued using `error_logger:format/2`.

So, if you don't want any error report to be printed, you can either change your reason to `normal` or `shutdown` or if you do want to return a custom Term as well, `{shutdown, Term}`.

```
handle_info({'EXIT', _From, _Reason}, State) ->
    {stop, {shutdown, partner_fled}, State};
```